# 404 page redirect to previous directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect to previous directory when user encounters an 404 error.
For example if page `www.examplesite.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/page.html` is not found, I wound user to redirect to `www.examplesite.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/`, if `www.examplesite.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/` is not found, redirect to `www.examplesite.com/aaa/bbb/` and so on. The only problem is that(in this example) user should go from `www.examplesite.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/page.html` to `www.examplesite.com/aaa/bbb/` without loading `www.examplesite.com/aaa/bbb/ccc`.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/[^/]+$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Say, you request `www.examplesite.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/page.html`, and page.html doesn't exist, you'll get redirected to: `www.examplesite.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/` and if *that* directory doesn't exist, you'll get redirected to: `www.examplesite.com/aaa/bbb/` and if *that* directory doesn't exist, you'll get redirected to: `www.examplesite.com/aaa/`, and if *that* directory doesn't exist, then you'll finally get a 404.

If you want it so the last step takes you to the root instead, then change the last line to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?[^/]+$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi Jon Lin, thanks for the help but i don't think it works as expected. It doesn't change directory and keep throw an 404 error.

Comment: The problem arises when the last charcter is '\'. How can be fixed?